# Switch between dropdown and text input based on $scope value AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-directive, dropdown

I am not very proficient in AngularJS, just learning as I'm going along. I've come across an issue which I really hope someone will be able to help me out with. Here's the situation,

I have a HTML form (viewDetails.html) which is currently displaying a dropdown box with multiple values. These values are obtained through the controller file (detailsController.js) by using **ng-options** over a $scope list defined. Now my aim is that if the length of $scope list is less than or equal to 1, the HTML should display a text box instead of a dropdown box. My code is as follows,

**viewDetails.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="manufacturerCode" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Manufacturer Code</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select ng-disabled="disabledParameter('manufacturerCode')" ng-model="firmware.manufacturerCode" ng-if="config.testing" ng-options="item for item in config.manufacturers" id="manufacturerCode" name="manufacturerCode" class="form-control" required>

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**detailsController.js**

```
$scope.manufacturers = []; // This is used by HTML to populate dropdown list
$scope.testing = true;    
var moremanufacturers = false;

// manufacturerCodes is populated from the database
if(manufacturerCodes.length > 1) {
   moremanufacturers = true;
   $scope.testing = moremanufacturers;
} else {
   moremanufacturers = false;
   $scope.testing = moremanufacturers;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot and Looking forward to some questions or answers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) { 
$scope.abc=[{id:1,name:"a"},{id:2,name:"b"},{id:3,name:"c"}];
$scope.enable=false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app=app>
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
Test
    <select ng-show="abc.length>1" ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="abc.id as abc.name for abc in abc "/>
    <input ng-show="abc.length<1" type="text" />
</div>
</div>
```